# merge to master, with different directory structure

Tags: git, git-branch, directory-structure, githooks

I have the following directory/contents structure on my `develop` branch:

```
boilerplate/
.git/
.gitignore
web/
```

The `boilerplate` directory contains development tools like grunt, bower and others, which then they deploy assets to a `dist` sub-directory inside `web`.

Now, any suggestions on how or if is possible to release a version from `develop` to `master` with just some specific contents from `web`? Just so it contains a clean, ready to push to staging/live?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1) In the `master` branch, you could delete the `boilerplate` folder and then add it to the `.gitignore` file.

Changes to the `boilerplate` folder in another branch should then be ignored in the `master` branch.  Just don't ever merge `master` back into `develop` if you do that.

2) Another option would be to make `web` its own repo (ignore it in the parent project), and then commit/publish just the repo from the `web` folder.